# How to divide object properties into titled groups in RJSF form's UI, without modifying schema?

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

Let's start with a very simple [**RJSF schema**](https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/docs/json-schema) of a single flat object:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Foo"
    },
    "bar": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Bar"
    },
    "baz": {
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "Baz"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to **visually** divide the object's properties into headlined groups - achieving the visual equivalent of grouping them under separate sub-objects with title - like this:

[image]

**But I want this to be a visual presentation of the schema I have**, I don't want to re-define the schema itself just because this is how I currently want to present it.

I would be fine with either

1. Finding a way to render the object's properties as a group

   - it seems like [object theme templates](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.1/advanced-customization/#object-field-template) could be extremely useful here! If only I knew how to re-use the built-in `ObjectFieldTemplate` (I use the [default bootstrap 3 theme](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/v4.2.2/usage/themes/)) - then I could create a custom wrapper around multiple instances of it. But the built-in (default) `ObjectFieldTemplate` doesn't seem to be exported from `@rjsf/core`. Trying to manually re-create its behavior sounds like a terrible idea to me
   - I know I can transform the `schema` right before I provide it to `<Form>`, but this would also require transorming `formData` both when providing to `<Form>` and `onChange` - I would prefer a more declarative way of doing this.
2. Arbitrarily adding a headline between the fields

   - kind of like a fake field with a custom widget, but without adding a new property to `formData` when submitting a form
   - injecting a fake prop into `schema` when passing into `<Form>` and removing it `onChange` feels really hacky
   - I would - reluctantly - settle for a custom widget that could inject title over a field, something like `ui:TextWithHeadlineWidget`, but I'm running into the same problem as with `ObjectFieldTemplate` above - I don't know how to wrap around the built-in widget, because I don't know how to import and reuse it

Do I have any good options here?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `@rjsf/core` does export its templates, just hidden under `getDefaultRegistry` function - we can get it like this:

```js
import Form, { getDefaultRegistry } from "@rjsf/core";

const registry = getDefaultRegistry();
const ObjectFieldTemplate = registry.templates.ObjectFieldTemplate;
```

[Other theme packages](https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form/tree/main/packages) seem to all export templates on a `generateTemplates` function instead.

Here is a working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/rjsf-5-playground-gpeeps?file=/src/Test.tsx